# nth child to target 2nd, 3rd, 5th, 6th, 8th 9th etc

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'd like to target the following the children elements:

```
.row .column:last-child .column:nth-child(2),
 .row .column:last-child .column:nth-child(3),
 .row .column:last-child .column:nth-child(5),
 .row .column:last-child .column:nth-child(6),
 .row .column:last-child .column:nth-child(8),
 .row .column:last-child .column:nth-child(9) {
...
```

but is there a better way to write this?

Comment: with css only? I guess no.

Comment: with css only , and if you have some kind of pattern (say all even child)? I guess yes.

Comment: Do you actually mean to target **every** 2nd, 3rd, etc. child, or just **the** 2nd, 3rd, ...?

Comment: 2nd, 3rd, 5th, 6th, 8th, 9th etc, that pattern

Comment: You mean everything except 1st, 4th, 7th, 10th, ...?

Comment: Your title does not match your example

Comment: yes siguza that's it

Comment: sorry alex updated it now

Comment: @user1937021: Did my answer solve your problem or are you still looking for something more. Please clarify.

Comment: @user1937021 please accept the answer if it helped, feedback is always welcome.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the below combination of the below two selectors to select 2nd, 3rd, 5th, 6th elements and so on in the same pattern.

- `:nth-child(3n-1)` - Selects 2nd (= 3*1 - 1), 5th (= 3*2 - 1), 8th (= 3*3 - 1), ...
- `:nth-child(3n)` - Selects 3rd (3*1), 6th (3*2), 9th (3*3), ...

```
li:nth-child(3n),
li:nth-child(3n-1) {
  color: red;
}
```

```css
.column:nth-child(3n),
.column:nth-child(3n-1) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** Be careful while using a class in the nth-child selector because the selector will not count just the elements with that class alone. CSS would style every nth-element which also happens to have that class.

So, in the below sample the 3rd element will not get the style because it does not have the `class='column'`. The 4th element will also not get the style (even though it is the 3rd child to have the required class) because as mentioned earlier `nth-child` counts all children and not just the children with the mentioned class.

```css
.column:nth-child(3n),
.column:nth-child(3n-1) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is targeting based on the OR of the three conditions (descendant of .row OR last child of .column type OR nth child of .column type).

This approach targets a specific child within a specific child count:

```css
/* 9 items, match item 2: */
.column:first-of-type:nth-last-of-type(9) ~ .column:nth-of-type(2)
{
  color: red;
}

/* 9 items, match item 3: */
.column:first-of-type:nth-last-of-type(9) ~ .column:nth-of-type(3)
{
  color: red;
}

/* 9 items, match item 5: */
.column:first-of-type:nth-last-of-type(9) ~ .column:nth-of-type(5)
{
  color: red;
}

/* 9 items, match item 6: */
.column:first-of-type:nth-last-of-type(9) ~ .column:nth-of-type(6)
{
  color: red;
}

/* 9 items, match item 8: */
.column:first-of-type:nth-last-of-type(9) ~ .column:nth-of-type(8)
{
  color: red;
}

/* 9 items, match item 9: */
.column:first-of-type:nth-last-of-type(9) ~ .column:nth-of-type(9)
{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
  <li class='column'>1</li>
</ul>
```

I have found the above useful for applying weighted column widths that change when the child count changes.

An extra bit of knowledge on this subject would be matching the first child of 9 children (as it is done differently, that is, without the Adjacent Sibling "~" operator):

```css
    /* 9 items, match item 1: */
    .column:first-of-type:nth-last-of-type(9)
    {
      color: green;
    }
```

```html
    <ul>
     <li class='column'>1</li>
     <li class='column'>1</li>
     <li class='column'>1</li>
     <li class='column'>1</li>
     <li class='column'>1</li>
     <li class='column'>1</li>
     <li class='column'>1</li>
     <li class='column'>1</li>
     <li class='column'>1</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I'm surprised nobody mentioned the easy and native CSS `:first-child` which can be negated as `:not(:first-child)`.
In your case, you can replace this huge selector :

```css
.row .column:last-child .column:nth-child(2),
 .row .column:last-child .column:nth-child(3),
 .row .column:last-child .column:nth-child(5),
 .row .column:last-child .column:nth-child(6),
 .row .column:last-child .column:nth-child(8),
 .row .column:last-child .column:nth-child(9) {
   ...
}
```

with the following :

```css
.row .column:last-child .column:not(:first-child):not(:nth-child(4)):not(:nth-child(7)):not(:nth-child(9+n)) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: This will also select the 4th, 7th and 10+th child, which the original selector does not have

Comment: @aabdulahad : I've updated the one liner selector to match your comment and the initial question.